# having this error:TypeError: function() missing 4 required positional arguments: 's', 'si', 'l', and 'n'

Tags: python, data-analysis

I was working on my sensitivity analysis project and having that kind of error.

```
from SALib.sample import saltelli
from SALib.analyze import sobol
import numpy as np

def function(k,s,si,l,n):
    return(3022061 + 1051 * k * si - 130751 * + 1513 * k * k - 224 * l * n - 3240 * k * s )

problem = {'num_vars' : 5,
           'names' : ['k','s','si','l','n'],
           'bounds' : [[42,45],
                       [0.26,0.33],
                       [0.28,0.32], [80,180], [2,5]]

           }

parameter_values = saltelli.sample(problem, 100, calc_second_order=False)

Y = function(k,s,si,l,n)
```

Comment: This is not the part of the code that caused the error. Please add the traceback you've got.

Comment: You only provide 3 arguments: 1 - problem, 2 - 100, 3 - calc_second_order=False. Might be that replace `=` with `,`

Comment: "C:\Users\Fabrizio Aranda\All programming shit\python.exe" "C:/Users/Fabrizio Aranda/PycharmProjects/Hello world/app.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Fabrizio Aranda/PycharmProjects/Hello world/app.py", line 18, in <module>
    Y = function(parameter_values)
TypeError: function() missing 4 required positional arguments: 's', 'si', 'l', and 'n'

Answer (score 0):

In the current code you gave, there is no instantiation of the variables k, s, si, l, n. So as you can read in the error message, thats exactly the problem.

Comment: I am relatively new and still learning, can you help me elaborate on what you mean? Thanks